# Unable to Extract and Merge Two Datasets Sharing a Common Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a code that reads in 2 CSVs as dataframes (they share a common column) and merges them through comparison of that column. One CSV has about 94,000 rows, and the other has about 40,000 (there are duplicate rows of the common column in the larger dataset, and it is important that I keep these duplicates).

Both datasets have the same column name on which they should merge, but I think that currently the merge is failing because one dataset has added characters that don't allow for comparison between the shared column. I've tried many different things to extract these characters, but nothing has worked so far. When I get the resultant merge dataframe, it's entirely empty.

Assume I have two dataset likes this:

Dataset 1:

**Note:** Dataset 2's ID column is actually made up of strings, but the apostrophes do not appear in printing, and I wanted to illustrate this here.

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'A':[4, 4, 4], 'B': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'ID':['111', '222', '333']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Dataset 2:

```
data2 = {'C':[3, 3, 3], 'D': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'ID':[111, 222, 333]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

How do I strip Dataset 1 of the apostrophes?

Things I have tried so far are:

1) Converting shared column to strings (yields result above)
    import pandas as pd

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('Data1.csv', index_col = [0])
df2 = pd.read_csv('Data2.csv', index_col = [0])
df2['ID'] = df2['ID'].apply(str) (this did not give me the apostrophes at the ends)
```

2) Stripping the strings in df1 of the '

```
for x in range(0, len(df1['ID']):
    df1.iloc[x]['ID'] = df1.iloc[x]['ID'].strip(')
```

3) Adding apostrophes to df2

```
for x in range(0, len(df2['ID']):
    df2.iloc[x]['ID'] = "'" + df2.iloc[x]['ID'] + "'"
```

4) Moving df1 to a Google sheets and using Power Tools to remove ' from this column (This worked, but I can't do it for my larger datasets)

None of the code I tried was able to eliminate the apostrophes.

I then merge like this:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID'])

df3.to_csv('Dataset3'.csv')
```

However, when I do this, I always get an empty dataset (as if the code couldn't find any common values), but with the correct column headers.

What can I do to strip the apostrophes from these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this code working on my machine to remove apostrophe's:

```
data = {'A':[4, 4, 4], 'B': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'ID':["'111'", "'222'", "'333'"]}
# note I added apostrophes into the elements in ID

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
for x in df1.ID:
    x = x.replace("'", "")
    x = int(x)
    print (x) # x is now an int
```

Comment: @Bonnie Awesome, glad to help. If my answer did help you please consider marking it as the solution and upvoting.

Comment: Sorry, I just went back to check on the csv that processed, and it looks like nothing was taken out. I'm not really sure what's happening here, but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @Bonnie if you're able to, uploading the csv that is giving you issues may help us solve the problem

Comment: I figured out the problem! The stripping methods above will work, the issue was using .iloc to index my dataset. Apparently, pandas doesn't do assignment so well. Thank you so much for your help!